# Is it possible to have separate page numbers for the main text and list of figures, tables, bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am using overleaf for editing:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99, 
maxcitenames=3,
]{biblatex}
```

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to have page numbers in contents as following:

[image]

Comment: If you load the `book` document class, use `\frontmatter\pagenumbering{Roman}` and `\backmatter\pagenumbering{Roman}` before the front matter and the back matter respectively; and `\mainmatter` before the main matter

Comment: Depends of used document class. For example `book`, `memoir` ... enable dividing document on three parts: `\frontmatter` usually numbered by roman numbers, where is collected table of contents, etc,, `\mainmatter`, where is content of book, and `\backmatter` where is usually bibliography and similarly stuff.

Comment: @Ivan am very new to this, could you write an example code?

Comment: You should not have Roman numbers at the begin and then try to continue the Roman numbering at end of your document. That is simply confusing for the users. How should they know where to look for page IX?

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Ulrike Fischer, this kind of numbering could be confusing for the reader. Anyway here is one of the possible solutions. If you prefer lowercase roman numbers you can omit the first `\pagenumbering{Roman}` and replace the second one with `\pagenumbering{roman}`.

**EMC**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
 
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}\cite{knuth:ct}
\chapter{Two}

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But Bibliography should have roman number 5 and appendix to be 6. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: This is a very convoluted and not at all rational system of numbering pages. In any case, `\setcounter{page}{n}`, where `n` is an integer, should be for you. Note that if the bibliography starts on page 5 the appendix will start on page 6 only if you use the `oneside` option and the bibliography takes up only one page